# Is this why a satellite ejects mass (decreasing its mass) into space so that its orbital radius decreases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, rocket-science, propulsion

I was doing a Physics question and the question was: How does a satellite reduce their orbital radius. The answer was by ejecting mass (thus decreasing the mass) but it didn't explain more.

This is my explanation:

- The gravitational force on the satellite must be constant, and so as F = GMm/r^2, when you decrease the mass, you also decrease the radius in order to keep the gravitational force on the object constant.

Is this correct, or does the gravitational force change?

Comment: Is the ejected mass rocket exhaust?

Comment: The question didn't say but if I assume it is rocket exhaust, would the rocket eject the mass opposite to the centripetal force? This would mean that the resultant centripetal force would decrease as well as the mass of the rocket will decrease, and therefore the radius would decrease? I feel like my explanation is not correct

Comment: I believe thrusts are tangential to change orbital speed and thereby radius.

Comment: In the explanation you give in the "bullet point", you say "in order to keep the the gravitational force on the object constant".  But if I reduce the radius I increase the gravitational force, no?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation you have been given is confusing because (a) “ejecting mass” sounds as if it means some complicated mechanism for throwing stuff overboard, but in fact it just means firing engines or thrusters and (b) engines/thrusters can be used to decrease orbital radius, but they can also be used to increase orbital radius - it depends on the direction in which they are fired.

Orbital manoeuvres are a complex topic, but at its simplest, firing thrusters to increase orbital speed increases the height of the orbit’s perigee (the nearest point to earth) whereas firing thrusters to decrease orbital speed decreases the height of the orbit’s perigee. For more details read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_maneuver).

Comment: It might seem possible to off-load mass without providing mass.  Just leave it behind. But that requires a force to separate the mass from the satellite... thrust.  This is implied in this answer, but it might not be obvious.  Also, a single impulsive thrust results in an elliptical orbit, and there is no *radius*. This is also implied in this answer, but might not be obvious.

Comment: Ok yes, I totally understand now! It is much easier to think of mass staying the same, because then the only factor that makes the radius smaller is the speed of the satellite.